# how to upgrade rhel version from 7.2 to 7.3

Tags: rhel7

Apart from doing yum update all, is there any way to update RHEL 7.2 to RHEL 7.2. AM looking for system packages alone to be updated and leave the application level to be in their current version.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by system packages you mean the ones supplied from official RHEL repos, and by application level you mean third-party software installed on top of the RHEL system. If that's the case, then disable the third-party repos for the upgrading process. I.e. something like:

```
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=rhel-7-server-rpms update
```

Alternatively, you can exclude specific packages from the upgrade. For that, you can use the `versionlock` yum plugin (available from the `yum-plugin-versionlock` package). Use it as follows:

```
yum versionlock <package>-*
```

This locks all packages whose names start with `<package>-` to their current versions.

Yet another method is to use the `--exclude` option of yum, or--to make it permanent--specify which packages to exclude in the `yum.conf` file. See [How do I exclude kernel or other packages from getting updated in Red Hat Enterprise Linux while updating system via yum?](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10185) for instructions on how to use those options.